# Insert Folders & Files In PHP

Tags: php

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Using Aurigma image Uploader I've put together the code below which allows users to upload location based images.

```
<?php

//This variable specifies relative path to the folder, where the gallery with uploaded files is located.
//Do not forget about the slash in the end of the folder name.
$galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/';

require_once 'Includes/gallery_helper.php';

require_once 'ImageUploaderPHP/UploadHandler.class.php';

/**
 * FileUploaded callback function
 * @param $uploadedFile UploadedFile
 */
function onFileUploaded($uploadedFile) {

  $packageFields = $uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageFields();
  $username=$packageFields["username"];
  $locationid=$packageFields["locationid"];

  global $galleryPath;

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $absThumbnailsPath = $absGalleryPath . 'Thumbnails' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  if ($uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageIndex() == 0 && $uploadedFile->getIndex() == 0) {
    initGallery($absGalleryPath, $absThumbnailsPath, FALSE);
  }

  $locationfolder = $_POST['locationid'];
  $locationfolder = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $locationfolder);
  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath . $locationfolder)) {
    mkdir($absGalleryPath . $locationfolder, 0777);
  }

  $dirName = $_POST['folder'];
  $dirName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $dirName);
  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath . $dirName)) {
    mkdir($absGalleryPath . $dirName, 0777);
  }

  $path = rtrim($dirName, '/\\') . '/';

  $originalFileName = $uploadedFile->getSourceName();

  $files = $uploadedFile->getConvertedFiles();

  // save converter 1

  $sourceFileName = getSafeFileName($absGalleryPath, $originalFileName);
  $sourceFile = $files[0];
  /* @var $sourceFile ConvertedFile */
  if ($sourceFile) {
    $sourceFile->moveTo($absGalleryPath . $sourceFileName);
  }

  // save converter 2   

  $thumbnailFileName = getSafeFileName($absThumbnailsPath, $originalFileName);
  $thumbnailFile = $files[1];
  /* @var $thumbnailFile ConvertedFile */
  if ($thumbnailFile) {
    $thumbnailFile->moveTo($absThumbnailsPath . $thumbnailFileName);
  }

  //Load XML file which will keep information about files (image dimensions, description, etc).
  //XML is used solely for brevity. In real-life application most likely you will use database instead.
  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');

  //Save file info.
  $xmlFile = $descriptions->createElement('file');
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('name', $_POST['folder'] . '/' . $originalFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('source', $sourceFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('size', $uploadedFile->getSourceSize());
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('originalname', $originalFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('thumbnail', $thumbnailFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('description', $uploadedFile->getDescription());
  //Add additional fields
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('username', $username);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('locationid', $locationid);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('folder', $dirName);
  $descriptions->documentElement->appendChild($xmlFile);
  $descriptions->save($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');
}

$uh = new UploadHandler();
$uh->setFileUploadedCallback('onFileUploaded');
$uh->processRequest();
?>
```

This code, in addition to the original script creates a 'location' folder with it's name derived from the 'locationid' value.

I've now come across a problem which I just can't seem to find the solution to.

When the user adds an image, the original image, a file entitled 'files.xml' and a folder called Thumbnails containing a thumbnail version of the image are created and saved in a folder called 'UploadedFiles'.

What I'm trying to do is to move the afore mentioned files into my 'location' folder, so the structure would be:

**Uploaded Files (Folder)**

- **Location (subfolder)**, containing original image, 'files.xml', Thumbnails folder containing and thumbnail image

I'm certainly not an expert in PHP, but I've tried to follow the format of the existing code creating:

```
$locationpath = $locationfolder
$abslocationpath = realpath($locationpath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

I then tried to point the various files and folders I want to move to `$abslocationpath` but this doesn't work. I'm sure that the answer lies within creating a new directory, but I'm at a loss about how to do this.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps provide some guidance please on how I can create the relevant directory and move the files to the new folder structure I want to create.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, however, I don't see where you make any calls that actually move anything to the locations path.

I've modified your code slightly. Please first look through it, paying attention to the commented lines and make adjustments accordingly and let me know if it produces the desired results:

```
require_once 'Includes/gallery_helper.php';
require_once 'ImageUploaderPHP/UploadHandler.class.php';
$galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/';

function onFileUploaded($uploadedFile) {
  global $galleryPath;

  $packageFields = $uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageFields();
  $username=$packageFields["username"];
  $locationid=$packageFields["locationid"];
  $locationfolder = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $_POST['locationid']);
  $dirName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $_POST['folder']);

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $locationfolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $absThumbnailsPath = $absGalleryPath . 'Thumbnails' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath)) mkdir($absGalleryPath, 0777, true);
  chmod($absGalleryPath, 0777);
  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath . $dirName)) mkdir($absGalleryPath . $dirName, 0777, true);
  chmod($absGalleryPath . $dirName, 0777);

  if ($uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageIndex() == 0 && $uploadedFile->getIndex() == 0)
    initGallery($absGalleryPath, $absThumbnailsPath, FALSE);

  $originalFileName = $uploadedFile->getSourceName();
  $files = $uploadedFile->getConvertedFiles();
  $sourceFileName = getSafeFileName($absGalleryPath, $originalFileName);
  $sourceFile = $files[0];

  if ($sourceFile) $sourceFile->moveTo($absGalleryPath . $sourceFileName);
  $thumbnailFileName = getSafeFileName($absThumbnailsPath, $originalFileName);
  $thumbnailFile = $files[1];
  if ($thumbnailFile) $thumbnailFile->moveTo($absThumbnailsPath . $thumbnailFileName);

  $xmlFile = $descriptions->createElement('file');
  // <-- please check the following line
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('name', $_POST['folder'] . '/' . $originalFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('source', $sourceFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('size', $uploadedFile->getSourceSize());
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('originalname', $originalFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('thumbnail', $thumbnailFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('description', $uploadedFile->getDescription());
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('username', $username);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('locationid', $locationid);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('folder', $dirName);

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');
  $descriptions->documentElement->appendChild($xmlFile);
  $descriptions->save($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');
}

$uh = new UploadHandler();
$uh->setFileUploadedCallback('onFileUploaded');
$uh->processRequest();
```

Comment: Hi @Authman Apatira wow! This is absolutely spot on, and it works a treat. thank you so very much for your help. Kind regards

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance

Comment: Hi @Authman Apatira, I'm really sorry to bother you with this. There's just one piece missing. If you look at my original code there was a folder created under '$dirName'. I can see that you add this to the xml file, but I can't find where the folder is created. Could you perhaps provide some guidance on where I need to incorporate this please. Kind regards

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this, but unfortunately it's not working. The individual files are being saved correctly as is the 'Thumbnails' folder. Could you perhaps tell me please where I'm going wrong? Kind regards

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page -- the issue you are currently experiencing is that the `$dirName` folder is not being created? Or are there files that are supposed to exist in that folder?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your continued help. Yes that's right and, as with all the other files and folders, it should be in the 'location' folder. I can confirm that it doesn't contain any files. Kind regards

Comment: Can do you me a favor? FTP into your web site and manually check the permissions of your location folder to ensure it is properly being set as 777. Also be sure to refresh the ftp view just in case before checking so that nothing is cached.

Comment: Hi, no problem at all. I've just checked and this is being shown as '755'. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Try the above modified code. If that doesn't work, the reason is not due to the code, but rather because your web host has restricted your web daemon from creating 0777 folders. You will have to set the 0777 permission via your FTP account (in place of where i have executed chmod). You will find an example on how to do that here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#104301 Best of luck!

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for your help, it's really gratefully received. All the best and regards.